# Last iteration of "forEach" loop adds extra period

Tags: kotlin, foreach

I'm new to kotlin and for practice, I had to use a "forEach" loop to print this from a text file:

```
*** Welcome to Taernyl's Folly ***
Dragon's Breath................5.91
Shirley temple.................4.12
Goblet of la croix.............1.22
Pickled camel hump.............7.33
Iced boilermaker..............11.22
```

The in the file looks like this:

```
shandy,Dragon's Breath,5.91  
elixir,shirley temple,4.12  
meal,goblet of la croix,1.22  
desert,pickled camel hump,7.33  
elixir,iced boilermaker,11.22
```

so I saved each line In a list called 'menuFile' and then iterated through it to print it out like the above menu using this code:

```
println("*** Welcome to Taernyl's Folly ***")
    menuFile.forEach{
        val (type, name, price)=it.split(",")
        val x=34-(price.length+name.length)
        var dots=""
        val dot="."
        var padding=0
        while(padding<=x){
            dots+=dot
            padding++
        }
        println("${name.capitalize()}$dots$price")
```

The issue is that for some reason on the last iteration of the loop it always adds an extra period so that the last line of the "menu" is always not even with the rest of the items on the menu. It doesn't matter which of the items I put last it always adds an extra one.

Comment: Is it possible that each line except the last ends with an extra invisible character like a carriage return? Try printing the price and the price length in the loop and see if they make sense. If not, try trimming the line before splitting it. By the way, did you mean forEachLine? I don't know of a forEach function for a file. Or is menuFile a list of Strings?

Comment: yes menuFile is a list of strings split using this "\n" as a delineator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tenfour04 wrote above, you have problem with Carriage Return (CR).
If you print price.length you will see that 7.33 has the same length as 11.22 :)
If you don't know how to remove it you can just save file bignerdranch.com/​solutions/​tavern-menu-data.txt instead of copy/paste :)

You can use "repeat" for generating dots.

Comment: I fixed It by adding a comma at the end of each line so that when each line gets split it didn't add in the space in between one line and the next.